# Spring boot - new project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I would like to create a java project (none web)  to take advantage of the spring features like dependency injection, transactional data, Autowiring etc,

Some of the features I would like to use:

- @Service
- @Autowired
- @Repository
- @Transactional
- JdbcTemplate

**Stuff I don't need:**

- Hibernate
- @Controller
- @Path

I am struggling to create that initial Spring project with the initial configuration
I was wondering if I can create that initial Spring project using the new spring boot integration in eclipse?
if its possible what is the correct modules to select from this screen?

[image: spring boot integration in eclipse]

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-non-web-application-example/ but also check https://start.spring.io/ where you can choose desired features and maven or gradle project is generated for you.

Comment: If you select one, it *should* have a description of what it provides on the right.

Comment: http://start.spring.io looks exactly like this wizard in eclipse, what to choose there is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The annotations are included in the org.springframework (spring-context) so if you create the default project you will get a pom with the spring-boot-starter dependency which includes the org.springframework.

Regarding to the JDBC it's included in the spring-boot-starter-jdbc.

Answer (score 1):

I think selecting `Aspects` from `Core` for all annotations except `@Transactional`. For `@Transactional` you should go within SQL and select dependency for any particular db that you are using like `PostgreSQL`,`MySql`,`SQL Server` etc.

Hope this helps !